# Auditing Sysmon 10 DNS events on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: dns, logging, windows-server

I have installed Sysmon 10 on a Windows 2008 R2 box in the hope of, amongst other things, capturing DNS requests.

Sysmon appears to be capturing all other Event ID's except for 22. I have installed this on a 2012 box with the same .xml configuration file and 22 is being happily logged.

Has anyone else noticed the same on a Windows 2008 box?

Answer (score 1):

According to Sysmon Documentation,

> [**Event ID 22: DNSEvent (DNS query)**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon#event-id-22-dnsevent-dns-query)
>
> This event generates when a process executes a DNS query, whether the
> result is successful or fails, cached or not. **The telemetry for this
> event was added for Windows 8.1 so it is not available on Windows 7
> and earlier.**

This explains why you don't see event 22: Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 share the same version number 6.1, whereas the equivalent for Windows 8.1 is Windows Server 2012 R2 (version 6.3).